# How to set the default location of the popup color picker HTML 5?

Tags: html

When we use input tag with type="color", the default color picker in HTML 5 will popup on the top left position. How can I adjust it to any location such as at the center of browser?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677423/how-to-position-a-color-picker-opened-through-html5s-color-input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to position a color picker opened through HTML5's color input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23677423/how-to-position-a-color-picker-opened-through-html5s-color-input)